# Why are rational singletons nowhere dense on the real line?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I'm trying to understand this using the definition that the interior of the closure must be non-empty for a nowhere dense set.
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Every** singleton subset of $\Bbb R$ is nowhere dense in $\Bbb R$. Let $x\in\Bbb R$ be arbitrary. Then $\{x\}$ is a closed set, so $\operatorname{cl}\{x\}=\{x\}$. Clearly $\{x\}$ does not contain any non-empty open interval, so $\operatorname{int}\{x\}=\varnothing$, and $\{x\}$ is therefore nowhere dense in $\Bbb R$.